# Map texture on 1x1 model threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

So I have a very simple box model that I want to put a texture (around 300x300) on.

Currently I have this code to load the material:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'materials/orange.jpg' ), shininess: 50, shading: THREE.SmoothShading })
```

The issue is that the material is just showing the top left pixel as it's a 1x1 model. I would like a way to have a texture stretch so it appears as 300x300 on the model.

Thanks for any help, Ed.

Comment: Check UVs of your model. What revision of the framework do you use? `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()` is deprecated. Use `THREE.TextureLoader().load()` instead.

Comment: Oh cheers, I've updated the q with the new syntax. How would I check the UV of the model? (I have the newest version of threejs).

Comment: Did I get it correctly, that you load a model of the box and do not create it via `THREE.BoxBufferGeometry()`?

Comment: Yeah, I made a model in blender and loaded it in. I plan to use more complex models latter so wanted to be ready for that. Really appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: I'm not an expert with export from Blender. But there should be an option to include UV coordinates to you model. By the way, of you apply the same texture to the box in Blender, does it cover the box correctly?

Comment: I'm exporting the models as a .obj file. I use when I use smart UV unwrap in blender it works great.

Comment: So turned out I needed to apply smartUV wrapping to the model before export, now it works perfectly. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out I needed to apply smartUV wrapping to the model before export, now it works perfectly. 
I just went into editor mode in blender and opened UV mapping with the U key and chose smart unwrapping.